# Does React apply a shallow/deep compare in hooks's dependency array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, compare

```js
const memoizedValue = useMemo(() => {
  // factory function
}, [obj]);
```

Imagine `obj` has several nested props.

In this example with useMemo hook:

- Will React recompute the value given by the factory function if the **reference** to `obj` changes?

or

- It applies a **deep/shallow compare** on `obj` and then recompute
  the value **if some prop have changed**, regardless of its reference?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Will React recompute the value given by the factory function if the
> reference to obj changes?

From what I know and understand, React uses shallow reference equality checks using [`Object.is`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is). Relevant condition is emphasized.

> `Object.is()` determines whether two values are [the same value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#same-value_equality_using_object.is).
> Two values are the same if one of the following holds:
>
> - both `undefined`
> - both `null`
> - both `true` or both `false`
> - both strings of the same length with the same characters in the same order
> - ***both the same object (meaning both values reference the same object in memory)***
> - both `BigInts` with the same numeric value
> - both `symbols` that reference the same symbol value
> - both numbers and
>
>   - both +0
>   - both -0
>   - both NaN
>   - or both non-zero, not NaN, and have the same value

Consider the following code:

```js
function App() {
  const [c, setC] = React.useState(0);
  const [obj, setObj] = React.useState({ prop: 10 });

  const forceRender = () => setC((c) => c + 1);

  const memoizedValue1 = React.useMemo(() => {
    console.log("`obj` dependency updated, recomputing value.");
    return obj.prop;
  }, [obj]);

  const memoizedValue2 = React.useMemo(() => {
    console.log("`obj.prop` dependency updated, recomputing value.");
    return obj.prop;
  }, [obj.prop]);

  const immutableHandler = () => {
    setObj(() => {
      console.log("Immutable update returns new object.");
      return { prop: 42 };
    });
    forceRender();
  };

  const mutableHandler = () => {
    setObj((obj) => {
      console.log("Mutable update returns same object with updated property.");
      obj.prop = 13; // DON'T DO THIS IN REAL CODE, IT'S A MUTATION!!
      return obj;
    });
    forceRender();
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <div>memoizedValue1: {memoizedValue1} - memoizedValue2: {memoizedValue2}</div>
      <button type="button" onClick={immutableHandler}>
        Immutable Update
      </button>
      <button type="button" onClick={mutableHandler}>
        Mutable Update
      </button>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setObj({ prop: 10 })}>
        Reset
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

`memoizedValue1` is using the root `obj` object value as a dependency while `memoizedValue2` uses the nested `obj.prop` object value as a dependency. One button updates and returns an entirely new `obj` object reference while the other only updates the `obj.prop` value reference. When the entire object is replaced and is a new reference notice that both `useMemo` hook callbacks are invoked, but when only updating the nested `prop` value that only the second `useMemo` hook callback is invoked.

### Conclusion

React doesn't look more deeply at nested properties when comparing React hook dependencies.

Comment: just as a follow-up to this, a "hack" to get get react to do a deep comparison is just to use JSON.stringify() on the object of interest in dependency array

Comment: Thanks for your demonstrator. However it demonstrates strict equality checks, not shallow comparison. I wonder what "shallow reference" means?

Comment: @miellaby Can you clarify what you are trying to say in your comment? I don't really understand any point you may be trying to make. Shallow reference equality simply means if the dependency refers to the same object in memory, it's considered to be unchanged and the hook callback won't run, if it refers to a new object in memory, it's considered to have changed and the callback will run. This is how part of the React reconciliation process works with the React component lifecycle.

Comment: @DrewReese "strict equality" (ref1 === ref2) ; "deep equality" two objects are considered equals if recursively every primitives/comparables inside are equal; "Shallow equality" ("shallow" as in React "shallow comparison") 2 distinct references may be equal if 1st level content is strictly equals (the elements of two arrays, the attributs of two objects) without recursive call.

Comment: @miellaby Sorry, I understand strict and "deep" equality, but I was asking what your point was referencing these. React specifically uses an [`Object.is`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is) algorithm for the shallow ***reference*** equality check, the "both the same object (meaning both values reference the same object in memory)" condition of `Object.is`. Is this what you were asking for clarification on?